# how can I get ElasticSearch cluster configuration

Tags: elasticsearch

how can I get ElasticSearch cluster configuration, for example I wanna to know the current value of discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get cluster configuration using following curl request

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/_cluster/settings
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, but I got very few info, such as: {"persistent":{},"transient":{"cluster":{"routing":{"allocation":{"enable":"all"}}}}}

Comment: Can you try this,
    curl -XGET localhost:9200/_nodes/_all/settings

Comment: thank you so much Avr, I've select your answer. But the url still not be able to get the default setting such as: discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes. Is there any way we can get it.

Comment: If you are not getting means it was not configured in elasticsearch.yml. You if you set discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes dynamically then you can retrieve that setting using _cluster/settings or else you set through elasticsearch.yml(which is static) then you can retrieve that using _nodes/_all/settings . If you are unable to see that setting through both urls then you might not touched that configuration. FYI default value for discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes is 1. It is highly recommended to set it to quoram of your cluster master nodes.

Comment: Knowing some default setting values can be useful as well. Rather unsatisfactory that all setting values cannot be retrieved.

Comment: Furthermore, not all settings in elasticsearch.yml appear in neither /_nodes/_all/settings nor /_cluster/settings

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the settings including the defaults within the DevTools

```
GET _cluster/settings?include_defaults
```

or

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/_cluster/settings?include_defaults
```

if you use your shell.